# И, как ни скрежещут тормоза, / Никогда я не смогу простить / Друга(,) честно лгущего в глаза

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая в боярсской песни «День прощания старых друзей»?

> И, как ни скрежещут тормоза, / Никогда я не смогу простить / Друга(,) честно лгущего в глаза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*И, как ни скрежещут тормоза, / Никогда я не смогу простить / Др**у**га, честно лг**у**щего в глаз**а***.

Обособление идет по **[1-му пункту](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108)**. Причастие с пояснительными, или зависимыми, словами обособляем. Логическое ударение и на определяемом слове, и на обороте. Пауза ставится перед оборотом. Интонация подтверждает присутствие запятой.

[2-й пункт](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108), опять же, не подойдëт. Чаще всего там задействованы прилагательные (но и причастия тоже есть в примерах, но от силы 2 — 3). И логическое ударение падает только на оборот, не на определяемое слово. Паузы между оборотом и определяемым словом нет.